# How to run multiple Powershell Scripts at the same time?

Tags: powershell

so I have two .ps1 scripts that check for new Tasks every 60 seconds and I want to run them at the same time. I use them every day and starting them gets a little annoying.
Ideally, I want to write a script that I can run that runs those two for me.

The Problem is that as they don't stop at some point, I can't just start them one after the other and I can't find a command to open a new PS ISE instance. However, one instance can't run both scripts at the same time. The Ctrl+T Option would be perfect, but I can't find the equivalent command.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to run the two scripts in ISE? If yes: why?

Comment: yes I do since they both load a local module...

Comment: you can load modules without ISE. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

I think what you want is something like

```
Start-Process Powershell.exe -Argumentlist "-file C:\myscript.ps1"
Start-Process Powershell.exe -Argumentlist "-file C:\myscript2.ps1"
```

In addition to that: Use `Import-Module $Modulepath` inside the scripts to ensure the availability of the modules.

Answer (score 5):

If you have Powershell 3.0+ you could use `workflows`. they are similar to functions, but have the advantage that you can run commands parallel.

so your workflow would be something like this:

```
workflow RunScripts {
    parallel {
        InlineScript { C:\myscript.ps1 }   
        InlineScript { C:\myotherscript.ps1 }
    }
}
```

keep in mind that a workflow behaves like a function. so it needs to be loaded into the cache first, and then called by running the `RunScripts` command.

more information:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/01/09/powershell-workflows-nesting/

Comment: One should mention however, that not all cmdlets are supported in Workflows and figuring out why a script does not work as expected inside a workflow can be quite a pain in the *.
Workflows are great nonetheless, but more fun if the code inside was developed with the thought "should-run-in-a-workflow" in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Use CTRL+T to create a new powershell instance (a tab is created, which is called powershell 2, I believe) inside Powershell ISE.

From the new Powershell tab you can now open a second powershell script and run it aside the script running in other powershell tabs.